# How do you write the opposite of a statement?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, writing-style, antonyms

For instance:

"I am joyful."

Is the opposite "I am miserable," or "I'm not miserable"?

The opposite of "I am" is "I'm not" or even "you aren't", and the opposite of "joyful" is "miserable". When writing opposites, do I write the opposite of each part of the sentence? Or only some parts? Obviously the two choices here have totally different meanings.

A longer example:

"I found myself asleep at the desk."

Is the opposite simply "I found myself awake at the desk"?

Or is it something convoluted like "You lost someone else awake apart from the standing station"?

Is it all interpretation? Or is there a rule for opposites?

Comment: Please define what you mean by opposite in the context of a statement.

Comment: The terms "logical opposite" vs "polar opposite" are sometimes used for clarity. The logical opposite of anything is just *not* that thing. So the logical opposite of "I am joyful" is simply "I am not joyful." Note that this doesn't limit you to misery; content, indifferent, and slightly miffed would all also fit into the "logically opposite" bin from "joyful". The polar opposite, on the other hand, is where miserableness comes in.

Comment: One. Just use the opposite of **one** thing to get the opposite meaning of the sentence. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @1006a I'm afraid that's way over the top for a beginner.

Comment: @Kris the OP doesn't sound like an English language beginner; this sounds more like an early logic/philosophy question. Logical opposition vs polar opposition is a pretty basic concept from that POV (I'm pretty sure it's mostly used in prepping for standardized tests that have a logic section, rather than by actual philosophers, in fact). Come to think of it, User178683, you might consider asking your question on the Philosophy Stack Exchange.

Comment: @1006a Now that's OTT for *me*.

Comment: @1006a That's very helpful. I hadn't considered this as a philosophical question, nor had I considered 'types' of opposites. Logical and polar opposition seem to be what I was looking for here, and those concepts will help me.

Comment: @Kris Thank you also for your point to change only one aspect of the sentence. In my mind, when I hear "opposite", I see how it could take many, many, many forms, so it's good to remind myself to keep it simple unless it is my intention to convolute the meaning.

Comment: @1006a Could the logical opposite of "I am joyful" also apply to the subject? For instance, if the logical opposite of _anything_ is just _not_ that thing, then could the logical opposite of "I am joyful" also be "_(Not I)_ am joyful" or "_you_" or "_they_" or "_he_ is joyful", or even "_nobody_ is joyful"? Or does opposition always apply to an attribute and depend on the contrast of a common subject? Could "joyful" be the subject of contrast, and _who_ experiences joy be the opposition rather than "I don't"? Or is that then a similarity or something else unrelated to opposition? Thank you.

Comment: There are lots of kinds of opposites. There's the complete reversal/antonym: joyful vs sad. There's the logical/set opposite (everything that something is not including intermediate things "I am not joyful" could mean that you're not happy but you're not particularly sad, but somewhere in the middle. And then there might be multiple dimensions (for words with multiple meanings). And then if you have a complex statement, any particular item could be chosen as an opposite or maybe it's the whole thing. It all depends.

Comment: We're really far afield of English here, so if you have more questions probably they should go in Chat. But basically, logical opposition is a way to think of the set of possibilities in the universe, those that fit the original statement and those that don't. Most of the examples you've given, of someone else being joyful, are irrelevant, because they are compatible with both the original statement being true and the original statement being false. That is, you could be joyful at the same time that he is joyful, or you could be sad/angry/blah (i.e. *not* joyful) while he is joyful. (Cont...)

Comment: Your last example, "nobody is joyful", is relevant, but it's too restrictive to be the logical opposite. The logical opposite is any case where you are not joyful, but now you've cut out some of those cases (the one where you're not joyful, but anyone else is). In other words, it's *part of* the set of cases that are the logical opposite, but it's not the whole logical opposite. @user178683

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this would be called in English and English grammar, but I do know that such a statement, i.e. the logical "opposite", if you like, of a given statement is called the 'negation' of that statement in Philosophy, Linguistics, the study of Logic, Mathematics and Computer Science - basically, every field that studies or in some way directly deals with logic.

For example, I would say that statement A is "I do have a bicycle" and its logical *negation* would be "I don't have a bicycle".

In short, the word you're looking for is **negation**.

Comment: There are multiple different ways of flipping a statement in logic, of which negation is just one, along with [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) and [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic)). The OP seems to be asking which one is the opposite, which isn't a question with a factual answer.

Answer (score -1):

'Opposites' (or antonyms) are words, not sentences (or clauses).
We use opposites (like any words) to complete the sentence. 
The sentences with different opposites differ in meaning.
So, to change the general meaning of the sentence (or clause) that's enough to use only one opposite.
For example:
I'm **hungry**. - l'm **full up.**
This taxi-driver is very **careful**. - This taxi-driver is very **careless**.
It's **lucky** that we got here **early**. - It's **unlucky** that we got here **late**.

When you use negative words (like *not*, *nobody*, *never*, etc.) we make the whole sentence negative.
In this case we don't use opposites.
For example:
I'm not hungry. = I'm full up.

Comment: What about the other way(s) of conveying the opposite meaning? The OP has a point there. See my comment at OP.